# Have problem with installation of testdisk

Tags: linux, installation, sudo

I don't know how to resolve this problem,can someone help me.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 testdisk : Depends: libntfs-3g861
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

This will remove all the independent dependencies. Then try reinstalling it.

Or you can also try following for removing broken packages as

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

Comment: I tried it, but it knocked me off so it could not be remove.

Comment: What happened exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the existing packages with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before running `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: I've tried it all but always throws out the same error.